# Function Continuity on an Interval.

Tags: calculus

h is a continuous function on interval [a,b] and h(x) belongs in Q for all x. Which statement is true?
(a) h is constant on the interval

Answer (score 2):

Another way to view it: Image of a connected set under continuous map is again a connected set.

Your domain $[a,b]$ is connected set, whose image is set $\mathbb{Q}$ which is totally disconnected set but a singleton set is connected, so the image must be a singleton set to preserve the property I stated above.

Hence your function must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

You have not finished writing the question but the answer is (a)... use the Intermediate Value Theorem to derive a contradiction for $h$ non-constant.